# Custom grunt configuration

Tags: gruntjs

I'm porting an application from php to node(sailsjs) at the same time trying to replace ant with grunt. I like the current project build structure and I would like to preserve some of it.

It looks like below...

```
project root
├── build (git ignored)
│   ├── coverage
│   ├── dist(to be deployed to target env)
│   └── local(to be deployed to local env)
├── lib
│   └── some library files like selenium..etc.
├── src
│   ├── conf
│   │   └── target/local properties
│   ├── scripts(may not be needed with grunt??)
│   │   ├── db
│   │   │   └── create_scripts...
│   │   ├── se
│   │   │   └── run_selenium_scripts...
│   │   └── tests
│   │       └── run_unit_test_scripts...
│   ├── tests
│   │   └── test_code....
│   └── webapp(this is where I'd like to place node[sailsjs] code)
│       └── code....
└── wiki .etc...
```

It doesn't exactly have to be the same way as above but more or less I prefer to build something similar. Now, pretty much all the sailsjs examples I have seen look like below.

```
project root
├── .tmp 
│   └── stuff...
├── package.json
├── tasks
│   ├── config
│   │   └── grunt task configs...
│   └── register
│       └── grunt task registrations...
├── tests
│   ├── unit
│   └── selenium
└── Gruntfile.js
```

Where should I place Gruntfile.js, app.js, package.json to achieve what I want? What other detail should I have to make grunt function and create artifacts as I want them?

**Note:** Obviously I'm not expecting to get all the details of grunt configuration. But I guess it helps to see where most important things go and how basic tasks could be configured.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a precise answer without a detail of your build steps, but I would suggest:

- `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` go to your root folder
- you setup your individual build tasks (whatever they are) to output to `build`: see the doc of each task on how to do that, it's usually the `dest` option

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you, yes, its helpful. What I ended up doing was placing Gruntfile.js and package.json at the root level. I also added grunt symlink task to symlink package.json and node_modules in my src/webapp folder. I'll post my solution here, once I fix all the small stuff... I also decided not use a build directory for local deployment, just running off of src/webapp locally. But I will use a dist folder for target environment deployments.